# MySQL the fastest way to count thousands of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, database-performance

I have MySQL database which consist of 13  tables. One table **transactions** will store in future a lot of data (nearly one million records). This table use InnoDB storage Engine. So business rules require to know amount of all records in this table. So, my question is what is the faster way to count all of this records?

**First**

Of course I can use something like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaction
```

but obviously this is not a best solution.

**Second**

I can create additional table where I can store incrementable variable

[image]

and add trigger which start executing when row was added into transaction table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_counter AFTER INSERT ON transaction
 ON counter
 BEGIN
 count_var = count_var + 1;
 END;
```

but what happens if 10 entries are added at the same time, for example?

And the last solution is to use information_schema. Something like that

```
SELECT TABLE_ROWS
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name = "transaction"
```

So what is the most appropriate way to resolve this situation?

Comment: Why do you think count(*) is "obviously not a best solution"?

Comment: You ask which method is fastest but then go on to criticize the first 2 of 3 methods - it's almost like you want us to pick the third solution

Comment: I would use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaction` unless there's a problem with that you're trying to solve.  Until you have a problem with that  you should use the most obvious solution.

Comment: _a lot of data (nearly one million records)_ so not a lot but some-..

Comment: Try #1 and #3 and measure them. Then decide.

Comment: I haven't a lot experience in database especially in MySQL that why i think that counting millions of records is not a good idea.But you think that this is appropriate solution?So, you are right i will measure and then make a decision.

Comment: The solution with trigger is the fastest. Why? Least amount of work is being done. You don't have to worry about "what if 10 inserts are made at the same time" - that's the job of a relational database and MySQL handles that well (the C in ACID stands for Concurrency and MySQL knows how to handle it). The solution with `COUNT(*)` isn't slow CPU-wise, but it's slow I/O-wise, depending on whether MySQL cached dataset to RAM or not.

Answer (score 0):

A "business rule" that requires the exact value of a number around a million?  Send that to Dilbert; the pointy-hair boss will love it.

Remember when search engines would show you the exact number of hits, yet they would return the value so fast that it was suspect?  Then they got a little more honest and said "hits 1-20 out of more than 120,000"?  Now they don't even bother.

You should as a serious question -- Why do you need the *exact* number?  Will an approximate number do?  Will the number as of last night suffice?

With those answers, we can help design a "good enough" computation that is also "fast enough".